# How do I pull data from google firebase whenever I want?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to pull data from a firebase database that I have made, I know that you can get the data when with the `.on('value', snapshot =>{...})`, but that won't work because I want to pull data whenever I want without being restricted to the`.on('value', snapshot =>{...})` "event"(or whatever it is called)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'd **highly** recommend rethinking your app into the reactive model that Firebase's `on()` method was made for. Reframe the problem from "first get the data, then do xyz on the data" to "start monitoring the data, now whenever we get the data, do xyz on it". Life with the Firebase Database will be much smoother after you've made that transition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `once` method for that. This way, you just fetch data at the time being.

```
database.ref('...').once('value', function(snapshot){
     // same way as .on method
})
```

Comment: Does that give me to pull data from the database _whenever_ i want?

Comment: If i understand you correct, you want to pull data when you want instead of listening an event for once. If thats correct, YES, you can use this method at any time to pull data

Comment: Besides, this is the recommended way in their documentation as well.